# What is os.system('pause') equivalent mac os?

Tags: python, macos, input, operating-system, pause

I'm coding something but I want that when the **user hit any key** (or a specific key if it is better) **to 'stop' the program until the user want to restart it...** I searched on the web and found the `os.system('pause')`; it's exactly what I want, but **I'm under mac os**, and the function is **only working on the windows os** module. **I don't want the user hit 'enter' after hit a key** (like `input('text')` function); I want the user **just have to hit one key**... Is it possible on **mac os**?

*Thanks in advance for answering !*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a single character from the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/how-to-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

Comment: `read -n1 -r` does this on Linux. Not sure if it is available on Mac, though

Comment: @Marat ``read`` is a shell builtin of ``sh``, so it is at the very least available on Mac via ``/bin/sh``.